# Send/sync files between Wear OS watch and Android phone without extra/companion app on phone

Tags: wear-os

I studied google doc https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer how to sync/send files between watch and phone but there is not stricte said if I need mobile apk on phone too. Seems MessageClient or ChannelClient needs a client app on phone side to receive data/files with the same signing certificate. Is that correct?

I saw apps in play store for watches which allow to sync files with phone but doen't require apk on phone side. How is it possible? What solution they used to transfer files?

thanks

Comment: Can you link to those apps? Apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrs.wear_file_explorer&hl=en_GB&gl=US have both mobile and wear apps.

Comment: You are right. I did better research. They have both apps for mobile and watch. So they can communicate each other. Without companion app on phone app on watch can't send data/file to phone.

Answer (score 1):

No, the companion apps on mobile provided by OEMs like Google and Samsung don't provide APIs for apps for Wear OS to access files.

The apps in the play store look like they all have mobile companion apps to provide that functionality.

Comment: Yes, I have notices that. They all have companion app on phone to handle file transfer. Thanks.